# comparing all the rows with in a group pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have dataframe as below, where I need to compare the row values of column `first_nm` and `sur_nm` within a group based on `company`. Based on the matching I would assign a value to `status` column in the output.

```
+--------+--------+----------------+--------------+
| company|      id|        first_nm|        sur_nm|
+--------+--------+----------------+--------------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE02|           JAMES|        FOWLER|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE03|          MONICA|        FOWLER|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE04|          GEORGE|        FOWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE05|           JAMES|        FIWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE06|           JAMES|        FUWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE07|           JAMES|        FAWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE08|           JAMES|        FEWLER|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE12|           JAMES|        FOWLER|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE11|           JAMES|        FOWLER|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0X|            Null|          Null|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Y|            Null|          Null|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Z|            Null|          Null|
+--------+--------+----------------+--------------+
```

For eg.

If both `first_nm` and `sur_nm` of all rows matches in a particular `company` - `status` is 0.

If only `first_nm` matches in a `company` group - `status` is 1.

If only `sur_nm` matches in a `company` group - `status` is 2.

If nothing matches or null values - `status` is 99.

The output dataframe is as below:

```
+--------+--------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| company|      id|        first_nm|        sur_nm| status|
+--------+--------+----------------+--------------+-------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE02|           JAMES|        FOWLER|      2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE03|          MONICA|        FOWLER|      2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE04|          GEORGE|        FOWLER|      2|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE05|           JAMES|        FIWLER|      1|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE06|           JAMES|        FUWLER|      1|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE07|           JAMES|        FAWLER|      1|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE08|           JAMES|        FEWLER|      1|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE12|           JAMES|        FOWLER|      0|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE11|           JAMES|        FOWLER|      0|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0X|            Null|          Null|     99|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Y|            Null|          Null|     99|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Z|            Null|          Null|     99|
+--------+--------+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

How can we handle this kind of compare within a column for different row values. Please guide.

Thank you

Comment: You have given a clear input and output as well. That's very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Your DataFrame (df):

```
+--------+--------+--------+------+
| company|      id|first_nm|sur_nm|
+--------+--------+--------+------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE02|   JAMES|FOWLER|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE03|  MONICA|FOWLER|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE04|  GEORGE|FOWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE05|   JAMES|FIWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE06|   JAMES|FUWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE07|   JAMES|FAWLER|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE08|   JAMES|FEWLER|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE12|   JAMES|FOWLER|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE11|   JAMES|FOWLER|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0X|    null|  null|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Y|    null|  null|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Z|    null|  null|
+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

1. Importing necessary packages

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, size, collect_set
```

2. Get the unique count of `first_nm` and `sur_nm`

```
unique_df = df.groupBy("company").agg(
    size(collect_set("first_nm")).alias("first_nm_size"),
    size(collect_set("sur_nm")).alias("sur_nm_size")
)
```

3. Apply the condition

```
company_status_df = unique_df.withColumn("status", 
                   when((col("first_nm_size") == 1) & (col("sur_nm_size") == 1), 0)
                   .when(col("first_nm_size") == 1, 1)
                   .when(col("sur_nm_size") == 1, 2)
                   .otherwise(99)
              ).select("company", "status")
```

4. Join it with the original DataFrame `df`

```
df.join(company_status_df, "company").show()
```

***Output:***

```
+--------+--------+--------+------+------+
| company|      id|first_nm|sur_nm|status|
+--------+--------+--------+------+------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE02|   JAMES|FOWLER|     2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE03|  MONICA|FOWLER|     2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE04|  GEORGE|FOWLER|     2|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE05|   JAMES|FIWLER|     1|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE06|   JAMES|FUWLER|     1|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE07|   JAMES|FAWLER|     1|
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE08|   JAMES|FEWLER|     1|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE12|   JAMES|FOWLER|     0|
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE11|   JAMES|FOWLER|     0|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0X|    null|  null|    99|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Y|    null|  null|    99|
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Z|    null|  null|    99|
+--------+--------+--------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Via multiple `when` conditions (to [`count distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.countDistinct.html) values in groups) on grouped `company` column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.join(df.groupby('company')
             .agg(F.when((F.countDistinct('first_nm') == 1) & (F.countDistinct('sur_nm') == 1), 0)
                   .when(F.countDistinct('first_nm') == 1, 1)
                   .when(F.countDistinct('sur_nm') == 1, 2).otherwise(99)
                   .alias('status')), on='company')

df.show(truncate=False)
```

---

```
+--------+--------+--------+------+------+
|company |id      |first_nm|sur_nm|status|
+--------+--------+--------+------+------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE02|JAMES   |FOWLER|2     |
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE03|MONICA  |FOWLER|2     |
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE04|GEORGE  |FOWLER|2     |
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE05|JAMES   |FIWLER|1     |
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE06|JAMES   |FUWLER|1     |
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE07|JAMES   |FAWLER|1     |
|SYNTHE08|SYNTHE08|JAMES   |FEWLER|1     |
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE12|JAMES   |FOWLER|0     |
|SYNTHE11|SYNTHE11|JAMES   |FOWLER|0     |
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0X|null    |null  |99    |
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Y|null    |null  |99    |
|SYNTHE09|SYNTHE0Z|null    |null  |99    |
+--------+--------+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: Won't this not work as desired if a company has both null and non-null values?